# Nuxt 3: useAsyncData with $fetch work only one time

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using nuxt 3 for a project and I want to make a request to a typescript file in `/server/api/` directory. But when I do in my file app.vue:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const createPerson = async () => {
    console.log('create person')
    const data = await useAsyncData('createPerson', () => $fetch('/api/file', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            lastname: fields.value.lastname,
            firstname: fields.value.firstname,
            age: fields.value.age,
            x: fields.value.x,
            y: fields.value.y,
            bio: fields.value.bio
        })
    }))
    console.log(data)
}
</script>
```

and when I call this function createPerson from:

```html
<button @click="createPerson">Apply</button>
```

my app fetch '/api/file' only one time and not re-fetching. If I use refresh function gived with useAsyncData, the first time I click on button I have two fetch and after one fetch.

Comment: If you disagree with how [SO] works, changing question titles to something completely unrelated to the question being asked is not the way to go. If you're interested in proposing a change for the better, consider posting it on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). It will surely be read and you'll get a few opinions. Continuing to abuse any [SO] privilege is likely to lead to you losing that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the extra functionality of `useAsyncData`/`useFetch`, you can simplify by just using the [`$fetch`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/utils/$fetch) utility on its own.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const createPerson = async () => {
  const data = await $fetch('/api/file', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
    body: {
      lastname: fields.value.lastname,
      firstname: fields.value.firstname,
      age: fields.value.age,
      x: fields.value.x,
      y: fields.value.y,
      bio: fields.value.bio,
    },
  })

  // ...
}
</script>
```

You also shouldn't need to use `JSON.stringify`, `h3` provides the [`readBody`](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#readBody) composable that will parse the body of a request.

```js
// server/api/file.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { age, bio, firstname, lastname, x, y } = await readBody(event)

  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you need to add a key to useAsyncData to force refresh your request. The reason a refetch is not happening is because `createPerson` as the key remains the same so a refetch is not performed.
So all you need to do is generate a random key using whichever method you prefer for useAsyncData

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const createPerson = async () => {
        console.log('create person')
        const data = await useAsyncData(RANDOM_KEY, () => $fetch('/api/file', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
            body: JSON.stringify({
                lastname: fields.value.lastname,
                firstname: fields.value.firstname,
                age: fields.value.age,
                x: fields.value.x,
                y: fields.value.y,
                bio: fields.value.bio
            })
        }))
        console.log(data)
    }
    </script>
```

You also have the choice of using the refresh feature without worrying about the key. Check the docs for this https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#refreshing-data